# Convert a column having mixed strings to epoch date pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame column with values like

```
$none
1558044313727
$none
1558058614585
...
```

I tried the below query, event with `errors='ignore'` it is not converting.

```
df['epoch_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['epoch_date'], unit='ms')
ERROR: ValueError: non convertible value $none with the unit 'ms'
```

How do I ignore $none or convert it into NaN values and rest all with datetime values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `errors = 'coerce'`:

```
df['epoch_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['epoch_date'], unit='ms', errors = 'coerce')
```

This will convert your `'$none'` values (and any other invalid parsing) to `NaT`, which is `NaN` eqivalent for `datetime64[ns]` types.

`errors = 'ignore'` fails because it simply returns the input on invalid parsing, so in the end it's trying to fit a string into datetime object, which fails for obvious reasons.